# Laravel queued jobs don't appear in new relic if worker runs as daemon

Tags: php, laravel, newrelic, laravel-artisan, forge

I noticed that the queued jobs do not appear in new relic as transactions of any kind.

After digging for a bit I found that if I run my artisan queue workers "straight" they do appear just fine but if I run them as daemons (That's what I have set for my artisan queue:work commands in supervisord config) they do not.

Why does it work that way? Is there anything that can be done about it?

I wanna keep them with --daemon set to avoid framework bootstrapping for every single job. However being able to see what's going on in new relic is important as well.

Scheduled commands and regular http requests seem to be tracked just fine.

I'm running Laravel 5.2 on several forge servers with both php 5.6 and 7.0.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

New Relic added out-of-the-box instrumentation support for Laravel Queues as an experimental feature in version `6.6.0`. Check if your agent version is at least `6.6.0` and then add this property to your `newrelic.ini`:

```
newrelic.feature_flag=laravel_queue
```

> For more info, check out the release notes: 
>   https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/release-notes/agent-release-notes/php-release-notes/php-agent-660169

Comment: did this ever make it into the standard release, or does it still need to be added manually?

Comment: Hi @djt - the instrumentation for Laravel Queues is still under feature flag so you’ll need to add the config option to enable it. We plan on defaulting this to "on" in the future.

Comment: Did this work with the `--daemon` option applied, i'm still not getting anything through.

Comment: for every person who will see this, `newrelic.feature_flag=laravel_queue` is ignored from v8.0.0.204 of the newrelic agent: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/release-notes/agent-release-notes/php-release-notes/php-agent-800204